# JGit throws ClassCastException in TransportConfigCallback

Tags: classcastexception, jgit

I am trying to use JGit. I tried following http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/12/09/jgit-authentication/ and the following block of the code throws a `ClassCastException`

```java
remoteRepository.setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback() {
    @Override
    public void configure(Transport transport) {
        SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
        sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(sshSessionFactory);
    }
});
```

Exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp
> cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport

What am I missing? I am using JGit version 4.10.0.201712302008-r.

Comment: can you show your import statements? You may have imported the wrong class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is only meant to handle SSH connections. If you are connecting through other protocols, you need to adjust the code to be aware that `transport` can be something different than `SshTransport`.

For example:

```java
command.setTransportConfigCallback(new TransportConfigCallback() {
  @Override
  public void configure(Transport transport) {
    if(transport instanceof SshTransport) {
      SshTransport sshTransport = (SshTransport) transport;
      sshTransport.setSshSessionFactory(sshSessionFactory);
    } else if(transport instanceof HttpTransport) {
      // configure HTTP protocol specifics
    }
  }
} );
```

Comment: Not sure why is the downvote , but the same code use to work and I am using ssh (ssh://git@ ...) . It also involves some debug efforts where I saw that the transport is coming as an HttpTransport (transport instanceof HttpTransport is true).

Answer (score 0):

when you set: cloneCommand.setURI("ssh://user@example.com/repo.git" );
Indicate the url with ssh protocol, the repo in github. 
Example - `(ssh://git@github.com:githubtraining/hellogitworld.git)`

Refer this https://github.com/allegro/axion-release-plugin/issues/101

Comment: thanks , I do not have enough reps to upvote ya , but the issue is that I did not notice I was setting http url instead of the ssh one in my test case